# Terms for cities and state to build dependent selects

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm adding a "City" field to a content type. I need it to be 2 dependent select lists. I mean, the user will select a state in the first select and the second select will be populated with the cities for the selected state.
In fact those are for Spanish *provincias* (states) and *localidades* (cities).

I know I can do this using the 'hierarchical_select' module, but now I need to create the taxonomy Terms for states and cities.

Is there any way to find and import those Terms (Spanish *provincias* and *localidades*) into my site? Creating these term is a daunting task.

Comment: I'll reformulate my question: I got 2 database tables (sql) for spanihs states and cities. How do I programmatically import them to drupal taxonomy Terms? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module [Taxonomy CSV import/export](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) which is very handy to import and create taxonomy terms or vocabulary.